Pass InputParams from CustomPage to PCF Control
I created a custom page and also a modern command.
This command gets the ID of the current entity or (if you are on a subgrid) the entity ID of the selected entity.
Now I'm passing the ID from my command to the custom page via:
const pageInput = {
            pageType: "custom",
            name: "we_technicaladdresssearchpage_5b4f6",
            entityName: OpportunityProduct.name,
            recordId: opportunityproductId,
        } as any;

        var navigationOptions = {
            target: 2,
            position: 1,
            width: { value: 90, unit: "%" }
        } as any;
Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(pageInput, navigationOptions);

On the custom page im saving it into a variable:
Set(inputParameters;JSON(Param("recordId")))

The question is now: How can I access this input parameter from a pcf-control embedded on this custom page?
Additional: Is it possible to pass a whole object? So I could load the entity already and pass it as a whole object to the custom page and then to the PCF?

What is the type of your PCF, is it a field or a dataset? Have you check the "context: ComponentFramework.Context" within you pcf? Maybe you dont need your input parameter, maybe you can find the details you need within the context.

Hi problem is already solved - and yeah in my case i need the input param, cause it depends if i'm on a subgrid or a main form
